# Global decomposition of reductive spaces

Tags: lie-groups

Consider a reductive homogeneous space $M=G/H$ with corresponding Lie algebra decomposition $\frak{g}=\frak{m}+\frak{h}$. Then there is a local diffeomorphism

$$
(exp\, X, h)\mapsto (exp\, X) h\quad \text{where} \> X\in {\frak{m}},\>  h\in H.\qquad (*)
$$

Is there an example of a compact reductive homogeneous space satisfying the following two conditions:

1. The curvature of the canonical connection is not zero.
2. The local diffeomorphism given in (*) is global.

I can show that any example will have to be non-symmetric and an $H$-space.

Condition 1 can be replaced with the equivalent condition

1.$^\prime$ $\quad exp\, \frak{m}$ is not a subgroup of $G$.